# NSImageView with Core Animation Gaussian Blur

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, gaussian, core-image

I have an image view that has a Gaussian Blur (Setup with CALayer in Interface Builder). My image fills the window and gets an undesirable transparent area around the edges as the image is blurred. Is there a way I can make a blur "layer" above the image view so it distorts the image without ruining the edges? I do understand the edge distortion is due to way Gaussian Blur works.

Thanks

[image: Blur]

This is the top left corner of the window

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, consider subclassing NSImageView and overriding -drawRect:, applying some Core Image filters to its image prior to drawing it? This gives you precise control over what's displayed while still keeping the original image set by the user.

Comment: I thought of that but I think it would produce the same effect because it would be the same filter (CIBlur).

Comment: Ah. I didn't read carefully enough, sorry. Really the only solution is to crop it by zooming in by the amount of the blur.

Comment: Thats the work around I'm using now but it's hard to get it perfectly accurate because the edges fade. I was just wondering if there was a better way to accomplish it. Thanks for the idea though.